# AttributeError: 'DocumentReference' object has no attribute 'document', why i am having this error, even if write accurate syntax

Tags: python, tkinter, google-cloud-firestore

i am working in python where i want to send data, which is vital signs, to firebase but i can't.here the button press sholud show the vital signs in labels, then send data to firebase. here in the firebase, i need t collection patients1-> which makes 4 documents-> and in each documnet there is the vital sign stored and updated with their conditions (if there is possible to store the vital sign without updating in the previous one and guide it to).

my code is follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

class RealTimeVitalSignsApp:
    def __init__(self, root, excel_file, column_name):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Real-Time Vital Signs")

        # Load Excel data
        self.df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/training data\data in XLSX format/b_1__p_id_5044545__d_2020_1_10__t_18_35.xlsx')

        cred = credentials.Certificate(
            r"C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/data-notification-71c1a-firebase-adminsdk-r3e79-8b41638df2.json")
        ###Down line use to connect the firebase database in the python
        #firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"databaseURL": "https://data-notification-71c1a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"})
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)  ##to connect firestore in the python
        self.firestore_db = firestore.client()

        # Create labels to display vital signs
        self.label_heart_rate = ttk.Label(root, text="Heart Rate: ")
        self.label_heart_rate.pack(pady=10)

        self.label_Blood_pressure1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Blood pressure(systolic): ")
        self.label_Blood_pressure1.pack(pady=10)

        self.label_Blood_pressure2 = ttk.Label(root, text="Blood pressure(diastolic): ")
        self.label_Blood_pressure2.pack(pady=10)

        self.label_Saturated_level = ttk.Label(root, text="Saturated level: ")
        self.label_Saturated_level.pack(pady=10)

        self.start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Start Updating", command=self.update_labels)
        self.start_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Set the initial value
        self.update_index = 0

    def update_labels(self):
        # Check if there are more rows to update
        if self.update_index < len(self.df):
            # Get the value from the DataFrame
            # current_value = self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['HR']

            current_data1= {'HeartRate': int(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['HR']),}
            current_data2={'Blood pressure(systolic)': float(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['BP1']),}
            current_data3={'Blood pressure(diastolic)': int(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['BP2']),}
            current_data4={'Saturated level': int(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['SPO2']),}
            # Add other fields as needed

            # Update the label
            self.label_heart_rate.config(text=f"HeartRate:{current_data1}")
            self.label_Blood_pressure1.config(text=f"Blood pressure(systolic):{current_data2}")
            self.label_Blood_pressure2.config(text=f"Blood pressure(diastolic): {current_data3}")
            self.label_Saturated_level.config(text=f"Saturated level:{current_data4}")

            # Increment the update index
            self.update_index += 1

            # Categorize the vital sign value
            current_data1['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signHR(current_data1['HeartRate'])
            current_data2['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signBP1(current_data2['Blood pressure(systolic)'])
            current_data3['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signBP2(current_data3['Blood pressure(diastolic)'])
            current_data4['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signSPO2(current_data4['Saturated level'])

            # vital_sign_category = self.categorize_vital_sign(current_value)
            # current_value['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_sign(current_value['HeartRate'])
            # Schedule the next update
            self.root.after(1000, self.update_labels)

            # Send data to Firebase Cloud Firestore
            self.send_to_firestore(current_data1, current_data2, current_data3, current_data4)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_value,vital_sign_category)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data1)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data2)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data3)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data4)

        else:
            # Reset the update index when all rows are processed
            self.update_index = 0

    def categorize_vital_signHR(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value > 100:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 60 <= value <= 100:
            return "Normal"
        elif value < 60:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def categorize_vital_signBP1(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value >= 160:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 120 <= value <= 139:
            return "Normal"
        elif 140 <= value <= 159:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def categorize_vital_signBP2(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value >= 100:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 80 <= value <= 89:
            return "Normal"
        elif 90 <= value <= 99:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def categorize_vital_signSPO2(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value < 85:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 95 <= value:
            return "Normal"
        elif 94 <= value <= 86:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def send_to_firestore(self, data_dict1, data_dict2, data_dict3, data_dict4):
        # Replace 'patient1' with the actual patient identifier
        patient_id = 'patient1'

        # Replace 'vital_signs' with your desired collection name
        collection_ref = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id).document('vital_signs')

        # Add a new document with all the fields
        # collection_ref.set(data_dict)
        collection_ref.document('HeartRate').set(data_dict1)
        collection_ref.document('BloodPressureSystolic').set(data_dict2)
        collection_ref.document('BloodPressureDiastolic').set(data_dict3)
        collection_ref.document('SaturatedLevel').set(data_dict4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace 'your_excel_file.xlsx' with the path to your Excel file
    # Replace 'HeartRate' with the actual column name you want to display
    excel_file_path = 'C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/training data\data in XLSX format/b_1__p_id_5044545__d_2020_1_10__t_18_35.xlsx'
    column_to_display1 = ['HR', 'BP1', 'BP2', 'SPO2']

    firebase_credential_path = 'C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/data-notification-71c1a-firebase-adminsdk-r3e79-8b41638df2.json'

    # Create Tkinter root window
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Create the application
    app = RealTimeVitalSignsApp(root, excel_file_path, column_to_display1)

    # Start the Tkinter event loop
    root.mainloop()
```